# Inconsistent display of an Array in Google-chrome console

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome

I am debugging a javascript file (d3.js). When I log an object to the Chrome console, I get an object with two properties: One property is called nodes and is an Array[14]. When I drill down to display the next level, the same property nodes is shown as an Array[5]. How is that possible ?

[image]

Comment: When you expand the object in the console that is giving you a live link to the current state of the object, which may have changed since the `console.log()` statement that originally logged it.

Comment: @Siguza - `console.dir()` also keeps a live link to the actual object. If you want to log the current state of an object use `console.log(JSON.stringify(yourObject))`.

Comment: thanks a lot! go ahead and answer, then I will accept it.